# Поиск слова в строке Python

Tags: python

Как написать условие которое будет искать слово в строке?

Пользователь вводит какую-то строку, например:

> меня звать Олег, мне 35 лет

Тогда Python проверяет, если в вводимой строке есть слово "звать" - тогда вывести `print("Привет")`.

Я делаю так, но не работает так как нужно:

```
if mess == u'звать':
print("Привет")
```

Если я введу "меня звать..." то ничего не произойдет

Если введу просто слово "звать" - то напишет "Привет"

Comment: Про оператор `in` пишут в любом учебнике по Python

Comment: @andreymal: `in` не различает слово от подстроки: "призвать духа" содержит "звать" подстроку, но не содержит слова "звать". `in` сам по себе не найдёт "звать" в "Звать меня ..." (регистр). Не говоря о "зовут меня ..." (форма слов)

Comment: @jfs это всё должен был написать автор в вопросе в виде «попробовал так-то, не получается». К тому же ни про регистр, ни про форму слов в вопросе не спрашивается

Comment: А ещё `in` различает слова вместо подстрок в сочетании с `spilt` :)

Comment: @andreymal: согласен, что вопрос следует дополнить. Двумя руками за был бы, если бы ваш первый комментарий попросил бы автора уточнить: нужна подстрока или отдельное слово? важен ли регистр букв (большие маленькие)? итд

Comment: В вашем случае лучше было бы написать вот так вот. if mess == u'звать': print("Привет")

Comment: Дополните ответ, почему у ТС это же не работает, а вы считаете, что это решение.

Answer (score 6):

Используйте регулярные выражения.

```
import re;
if re.search(r'\bзвать\b', 'меня звать Олег, мне 35 лет'):
    print("Привет")
```

Comment: А если входная строка "Олегом меня звать, мне 35 лет"?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов и для этой строки тоже отлично работает

Comment: @andreymal Вы правы. Мои знания по регуляркам немного отстали.

Answer (score 2):

Он сравнивает целую строку с условием "звать" соответственно "звать" <> "меня звать"
Я не чего не смыслю в питоне, я больше по sql.
Но немного загуглив нашел, у вас должно быть так. find метод поиска в строке ,возвращает индекс первого вхождения подстроки в строку, в случае отсутствия подстроки ,возвращает -1. Имеет вид `str1.find(str2,[start],[end])`

```
if mess.find('звать') != -1 :
print("Привет")
```

В sql server бы это выглядело так:

```
declare @a varchar(100) = 'меня звать'
if @a like '%звать%'
print ("Привет")
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не сделать просто вот так?

```
if " звать " in mess or " звать." in mess:
    print("Привет")
```

Comment: Сделайте, и опубликуйте пожалуйста результат.

Comment: `Олегом меня звать.` Не пройдёт.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Поправил код

Comment: @0xdb Поправил код

Comment: "Отозваться на крик". Не пройдёт.

Comment: @Эникейщик, так вопрос был задан  именно на слово "звать", а не на производные

Comment: Ну да. В моем примере слова "звать" нет, но ваш код даст положительный результат.

Comment: @Эникейщик, тогда почему вы написали что "не пройдёт", если код ответил положительно?)

Comment: Тест не пройдёт :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91128/discussion-between-arsen-aganesov-and-).

Comment: Да что тут обсуждать-то? :) Данный код не подходит для описанной задачи, т.к. может давать неверный результат.

Comment: @Эникейщик, автор не указал дополнительные сведения о возможных вариантах. Я поправил код,

Comment: Да неправильно всё это. А если вместо точки запятая? А если в начале предложения и с заглавной буквы? Будете все возможные варианты перечислять?